# Android ffmpeg apply video effects take log time

Tags: android

I am using below command to apply effect,its take 6-8 minutes to apply effect for 2 min video. Please help me to improve effective time for ffmpeg commands.

```
String commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i "
            + mVideoData.getPath()
            + " -strict experimental -vf curves=vintage -s 640x480 -r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 2097k -vcodec mpeg4 /sdcard/videokit/curve.mp4";
```

Comment: same problem i am facing.. have you got answer?